# Floating right inputs in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, css-float

I have form: http://jsfiddle.net/U8D3w/

```
<form>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <br />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" name="signin_submit" value="OKEY" />
</form>
```

Why does it have the wrong right behavior in chrome?

Comment: "Why it has wrong floating to right only in chrome?" Uh, whut?

Comment: If you tell us what is the "right behavior" we may be able to give a solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes right behavior, I edited

Answer (score 0):

"No i meand button and input not aligned "

your form element have a 100% default width... that's why...

Give him a width, or try to add display:inline-block to his style

Answer (score 0):

You're only adding a float to button[type=submit] that's why your button is onyl floating to the right.

If you want the button to align with your inputs, set a width to the container, so the button doesn't float out of the box. You might need to add a clearing class(with css attribute clear:both; ), to allow the button to stay inside the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/U8D3w/1/

```
form{
 width:505px;
}
```